# Facing issue while getting the parent object property in nested object using class validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have a two class DTO one is Order & one is product and is there any way to access the Order class  fields in the Product class?

```
export class Order {
  
  @Expose({ name: 'orderId' })
  order_id: number;

  @Expose({ name: 'products' })
  @IsArray({ message: 'products must be an array' })
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => Products)
  products: Products[];
 
}

export class Products {

  @Expose({ name: 'quantity' })
  quantity: number;
    
  @Expose({ name: 'sku' })
  sku: string;

}
```

I am able to access the current object but not able to access the Order class fields in the nested Products

Comment: Your product items will have to be given a link to the parent order. Other than being in an array that happens to be the value of a property on an order object, they have no relation to it.

Comment: For DTO, You can access the Order DTO class fields in product DTO class by extending it, using "export class Products extrends PartialType(Order){}"